# Color Bar only, with custom colors , values, and gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am new to matplotlib and struggling to plot a colorBar with custom values.

More specificly, I need to plot only a color bar, not the related figure, and for this I have a list of color values , as well as the corresponding values for each of these colors;

I tried essentially two different methods but cant get what I want :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

colors = [ #1A6AD0, #3D98E3, #79C4E9, #055A05, #99C48C, #AC8C1A  ]
values = [ -1800 , -1200, -1, 0, 600 , 1200 ]

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(2,4) )
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0.05, 0.25, 0.9])

# First option :
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("mypalette", colors, N=1000)         
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))  
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='vertical') # also tried to add ticks=values here but no ..doesnt work ..  Color palette has a nice gradient but values do not match their colors. not even with spacing = 'uniform' or 'proportional' ...

# Second option :
norm2 = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(values, cmap.N)
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm2, spacing='proportional' , orientation='vertical', ticks=values ) # Values correspond to the rights colors, but there is no gradient
```

So, my problem is that in the first case, I manage to have a nice color gradient, but the values ( which will be the ticks) do no appear at the right "color position" ( for example green faces 600 while it should face 100) 
All the trouble comes from the fact that my values are not evenly spaced I think. But I cannot change them !

In the second case, i have the proper correspondence between colors and values, but the colors are now discrete (appear by blocs), which is really annoying ( and not only for visual purpose)

I am especially expecting a quick color transition from blue to green for the values corresponding to -1 and 0

Unfortunately I cannot show here the pictures as I using a secure computer to program, but what I obtained in the first and second method are similar to the first two pictures in this page : https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colorbar-only-py

Of course, I what I would like to obtain, is a ColorBar with both a nice color gradient AND the right correspondence between colors <-> values

I have found and read different examples on the web especially here and on matplotlib documentation,  but damn ... impossible

Am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks a lot

[english is not my native language]

Comment: I'm having trouble running your example code. Did you want 0 in the center? If so, I'd make sure that your values go from -1800 to +1800

Comment: yes preferably I need to have 0 as it represents the sea level. Also I was able to see a problem was present because the -1 representing slightly below the sea level was in the green part ( and is encoded as light blue here). You can add +1800 with color #85886A if you want, but that should not change anything. The problem, I think comes from the fact that my values scale is not evenly spaced . Anyway thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to provide the corresponding positions of the colors when creating the colormap. Else, colors are equally distributed within the range of 0 to 1.
When supplying the positions, you cannot use the values directly, but need to map them to the unit interval. For this the same `norm` can be used as for creating the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = [ "#1A6AD0", "#3D98E3", "#79C4E9", "#055A05", "#99C48C", "#AC8C1A"]
values = [ -1800 , -1200, -1, 0, 600 , 1200 ]

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(2,4) )
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0.05, 0.25, 0.9])

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))  
normed_vals = norm(values)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("mypalette", list(zip(normed_vals, colors)), N=1000)  
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Just tried and give the expect result 
So I was missing the normalization to the 0-1 range of the values, plus the list (zip(vals,colors)) stuff.
Thanks a lot man, this problem was really bothering me !!